# get abstract class info declared in another module in base class module

Tags: python, inheritance

**UPDATE**: I am having trouble getting the names of inherited/derived class names declared in other modules in the base class module.

Use case: I would like to create a common interface to call the subclasses from the base class.

Example:

```
#basemodule.py
class BaseClass(object):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self, inputs=None):
        pass

def get_subclasses():
    #I want derived class information here
    for cls in list(BaseClass.__subclasses__):
        # call subclasses here

# module1.py
import BaseClass
class derivedClass1(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def method(self, inputs):
        # method implemented in derivedClass1

# module2.py
import BaseClass
class derivedClass2(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def method(self, inputs):
        # method implemented in derivedClass2
```

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't import the module, the parent class cannot know about subclasses. Just because you have some file somewhere on disc that uses the parent class doesn't mean the parent class knows about it.

Comment: @deceze, thanks for your reply. Importing modules of subclasses in parent class leads to circular import. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: What's the use case to begin with? Parents generally shouldn't be concerned about their children…

Comment: In the baseclass module, I want to call the method in all the subclasses and use their results in baseclass module,  and number of subclasses might increase later.

Comment: That sounds like bad upside-down design. Again: what's the use case exactly? Again: consider that you may have a .py file anywhere on disk in which a class inherits the parent class. How may you reasonably discover all those files from a clueless parent class?!

Comment: Use case is to iterate over the derived classes in the base class and create a common interface to call all subclasses. I understand what you said about the clueless parent class. Do you have a suggestion / work-around for this problem? Thanks

Comment: You don't iterate the derived classes because you want to iterate the derived classes. You iterate the derived classes because you are trying to complete some task. *What is that task?*

Comment: I hope the update of the description helps. The task is to create a common interface in the base class to call the derived classes.

Comment: This does not sound like good use of OOP at all… Since you're not very forthcoming with details, that's all I'll be able to say.

Comment: Sorry, but thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit vague, and lacks important details, like the error you're getting, and a bit more context regarding your actual goals here. Having said that, I've noticed a couple of things that might be the cause of the problems you're having:

1. `BaseClass.__subclasses__` is a method, therefore, you need to call it instead of accessing it, like you access a class property, or attribute. To do so, use `BaseClass.__subclasses__()` instead.
2. In order to your `get_subclasses()` function to work, you need to first import the subclasses. Otherwise python won't know which classes inherit from `BaseClass`.

### Corrected code

Here's the correct implementation of `get_subclasses()` function, as mentioned above:

```py
from basemodule import BaseClass


def get_subclasses():
    """Get subclasses from `basemodule.BaseClass`."""
    for cls in list(BaseClass.__subclasses__()):
        # call subclasses here
        print(cls.__name__)  # Added print statement to test the solution.
```

### Example

#### Without importing `module1`, and `module2`

Here's an example of the output from `get_subclasses()` I receive, when I don't import the modules that host the subclasses:

[image: First Example]

#### Importing `module1`, and `module2`

When I import both modules that host the subclasses, you then get the output I think you're expecting:

[image]

#### Full-code

Here's the full code of the examples:

```py
# my_pckg/basemodule.py

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class BaseClass(object):

    @abstractmethod
    def method(self, inputs=None):
        pass

# ================================================
# my_pckg/module1.py

from my_pckg.basemodule import BaseClass


class derivedClass1(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def method(self, inputs):
        # method implemented in derivedClass1
        pass


# ================================================
# my_pckg/module2.py

from my_pckg.basemodule import BaseClass


class derivedClass2(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def method(self, inputs):
        # method implemented in derivedClass2
        pass


# ================================================
# my_pckg/test.ipynb

from basemodule import BaseClass
from module1 import *
from module2 import *


def get_subclasses():
    """Get subclasses from `basemodule.BaseClass`."""
    for cls in list(BaseClass.__subclasses__()):
        # call subclasses here
        print(cls.__name__)  # Added print statement to test the solution.


get_subclasses()
# Prints:
# derivedClass1
# derivedClass2
```

### Important notes

The imports as shown in the example pictures won't work, if you're trying to use them from outside the parent module. In the example I just gave, here's the complete tree view of the entire package structure:

```
my_pckg
|______init__.py    # <-- Needed to make my_pckg submodules "importable".
|____basemodule.py  # <-- Hosts the BaseClass class.
|____module1.py     # <-- Hosts the derivedClass1 subclass.
|____module2.py     # <-- Hosts the derivedClass2 subclass.
|____Test.ipynb     # <-- Where the test from the screenshots took place.
```

If you want to import these modules from outside the package you have two options:

1. Create a setup for you package, and `pip install` it (use the `-e` flag to install it in development mode).
2. Import `sys`, and add `my_pckg` path to the known paths.

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, './my_pckg')
from basemodule import BaseClass
from module1 import *
from module2 import *


def get_subclasses():
    """Get subclasses from `basemodule.BaseClass`."""
    for cls in list(BaseClass.__subclasses__()):
        # call subclasses here
        print(cls.__name__)  # Added print statement to test the solution.


get_subclasses()
# Prints:
# derivedClass1
# derivedClass2
```

**For example:**

[image]

### Circular Imports

**Do NOT** import `module1`, and `module2` inside `basemodule`, as this leads to a circular import. This happens because when you import `basemodule`, python will see that the module needs to import `module1`, and `module2` and therefore goes to these modules. There, it finds out that both actually require `basemodule` themselves, so it goes back to `basemodule`. You can see that this becomes an infinite circle, where no module is able to be imported. To overcome this, place `get_subclasses()` function in a separate module, alongside all your necessary imports, like the example pictures.